# Accessing Properties in Array of Arrays? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var person = { firstname: "", lastname: "", email: "" };
var student = Object.create(person);

var i = 0;
var flag = true;

//create array of arrays. similar to a database. Receive unspecified number
//number of inputs from user
while (flag) {
var input = prompt("Please enter fname, lname, and email"); 
//Sample input: John, Doe, abcd@efg.com    

var results = input.split(", ");  

student[i]=({  
firstname: results.shift(),
lastname: results.shift(),
email: results,

});
i++;


console.log(student[i].firstname);//testing code. returns student[i] is undefined
console.log(student[0].firstname);//testing code. returns John.
flag = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
};
```

When I try to run this code I get the error `student[i] is undefined`.

Even though I pretty much set the values of `student[i]` in the code directly above it.
However, when I try to output `student[0].firstname` I will get `John`.

EDIT: Even with

```
console.log(student[i].firstname);
```

placed in front of the i++ it isn'tworking

Comment: You're incrementing `i` before the logging statements.

Comment: @steveax       it still doesn't fix the student[i] being undefined issue

Comment: Don't drastically edit your code after people have answered. Your shifting `i++` invalidated a whole bunch of answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the `i` and **then** you query the array. So when you put in a new item lets say the index 0, when you query the result back, you'll actually query the student 1. Move the `i++;` down after the `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you do:

```
student[i]=({  
...
i++;
...
console.log(student[i].firstname);
```

So you set `student[i]`. Then you increment `i`, so it is no longer the same value as it was before. Then you try to use that value to access a property of `student`, which doesn't exist because you haven't set it.

You need to reorder your calls. I imagine `i++` should be at the very end of the block.

Answer (score 0):

After you assign `student[i]` you call `i++`. This sets `i=1`. You have not set `students[1]` to any value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is make a `students` array, and then `push` new instances to that.

```js
var students = [];
var flag = true;

//create array of arrays. similar to a database. Receive unspecified number
//number of inputs from user
while (flag) {
    var input = prompt("Please enter fname, lname, and email");
    //Sample input: John, Doe, abcd@efg.com    

    var results = input.split(", ");

    students.push({
        firstname: results.shift(),
        lastname: results.shift(),
        email: results[0],

    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(students)); //testing code
    flag = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
};
```

Comment: P.S. You might want to split on just the comma (no space after it) in order to account for user input without that space. If you do that, then you'll probably also want to trim the leading space from each value if it's there. But that's outside the scope of this particular problem.

Comment: How would I access something like student[i].firstname for example? When I ran your code it just printed the entire studentobject?

Comment: You can access a student by index at any time. If you want to get the first name of the last student added, then `students[students.length - 1].firstname` will get that.

Answer (score 0):

That `i++;` above `console.log(student[i].firstname);//testing code. returns student[i] is undefined` is setting i = 1.

Comment: This answer has technically correct based on the code at the time it was written. The OP changed the code invalidating the answer.

Comment: @usert3551329 - Are you sure it is still not working? I just made a mock-up of your code, moving the i++ to between your two console.logs and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Move the i++ after your logging and change the way results is accessed

```
var results = input.split(", ");

        student[i]=({
            firstname: results[0],
            lastname: results[1],
            email: results[2]

        });



        console.log(student[i].firstname);//testing code. returns student[i] is undefined
        console.log(student[0].firstname);//testing code. returns John.
        i++;
```

Comment: student[i] is still undefined

Comment: Updated to change the way results is accessed. Student[i] wasn't undefined after we moved i++ but firstname wasn't getting bound properly.